# Missing script: "start" on nest

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs

i just installed nestjs and i'm running it in vscode according to the documentation i should be able to run the project by the code

```
npm run start
```

but i'm getting an error that im missing script: start

documentation says that it should give me hello world when i run the localhost port

```
0 verbose cli /var/lib/snapd/snap/node/6895/bin/node /var/lib/snapd/snap/node/6895/bin/npm
1 info using npm@8.19.2
2 info using node@v16.18.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:/var/lib/snapd/snap/node/6895/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 5ms
10 timing config:load:file:/home/ramanm/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:/var/lib/snapd/snap/node/6895/etc/npmrc Completed in 3ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 3ms
14 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 19ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 19ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 6ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 1ms
21 verbose title npm run start
22 verbose argv "run" "start"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 2ms
24 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
25 timing npm:load:display Completed in 6ms
26 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/home/ramanm/.npm/_logs
27 verbose logfile /home/ramanm/.npm/_logs/2022-11-16T12_34_58_739Z-debug-0.log
28 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 6ms
29 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
31 timing npm:load Completed in 41ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
33 silly logfile done cleaning log files
34 timing command:run Completed in 11ms
35 verbose stack Error: Missing script: "start"
35 verbose stack
35 verbose stack Did you mean one of these?
35 verbose stack     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
35 verbose stack     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
35 verbose stack
35 verbose stack To see a list of scripts, run:
35 verbose stack   npm run
35 verbose stack     at RunScript.run (/var/lib/snapd/snap/node/6895/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/run-script.js:98:13)
35 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/var/lib/snapd/snap/node/6895/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:78:5)
36 verbose cwd /home/ramanm/workspace/nestPrac
37 verbose Linux 5.15.76-1-MANJARO
38 verbose node v16.18.1
39 verbose npm  v8.19.2
40 error Missing script: "start"
40 error
40 error Did you mean one of these?
40 error     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
40 error     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
40 error
40 error To see a list of scripts, run:
40 error   npm run
41 verbose exit 1
42 timing npm Completed in 68ms
43 verbose code 1
44 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
44 error     /home/ramanm/.npm/_logs/2022-11-16T12_34_58_739Z-debug-0.log
```

```
{
  "name": "prac",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "28.1.8",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "28.1.3",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.8",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `npm update` or delete the `node_modules` folder and try to reinstall the node modules all again. i.e. `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`
You can also run `npm cache clean` to clear the npm cache.
If you didn't, you'd better install nest.js cli by running `npm i -g @nestjs/cli`

And

```
$ cd  /some/project/root/folder
$ npm install -D @nestjs/cli
```

Comment: still shows the same error Missing script:"start"

Comment: Did you try the above steps? @RamanMaharjan

Comment: What's the console output when you run `npm run` ?

Comment: Please try to run these: 
`$ npm install -g @nestjs/cli

$ cd  /path/project/root/folder

$ npm install -D @nestjs/cli`

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/scripts

Comment: thanks for your help i was accessing it from the wrong file XD